# Does informatica Powercenter 10.4.1 support Oracle Multitenancy (PDB/CDB)?

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are migrating from Oracle 12.cR1 multitenant to Oracle 19c Multitenant and from Informatica 10.1.0 to 10.4.1. Since it's not mentionned in the PAM , my question is
Does informatica Powercenter 10.4.1 support Oracle Multitenancy (PDB/CDB)?

Comment: Are you asking, if informatica can connect to a cdb or load into it- answer is yes. But are you looking for multitenant type architecture in informatica - probably you dont have it and you may think about using iics infa cloud.

Comment: I'm asking if Informtica can connect (DOMAIN and REPOSITORY) and load into a PDB

Comment: i think it should be - if its an oracle db. you can test it out.

Comment: Use of multi-tenancy database is essentially transparent to the client; it should work fine.